# getting object's properties values without knowing their name?

Tags: c#

```
class A
{
    public string a { get; set; } 
    --and so on--   //lets we have 30-50 class variables//
}
```

i know its bad. but how can i get the values of all variables by just looping and without knowing their name just with  object or instanse of class?

like

```
for(int i;i<30;i++)
{
    variable[i] = object.? ;
}
```

Comment: can some give me little example?

Answer (score 6):

Use reflection.

```
typeof(A).GetFields()
typeof(A).GetProperties()
```

Comment: keep in mind though that reflection is a performance killer...I tried it in an OR/M once to do some automatic mapping

Comment: @Ozzy: It depends what you're doing - and which version of .NET you're using. I believe it improved a lot between CLR 1 and CLR 2 for example. You can also take a one-off hit to create delegates to fetch each field/property - which can make it much, much faster.

Comment: @Jon Is there any way to take advantage of dynamic stuff introduced in .NET 4?
AFAIK dynamic implements `IDictionary`.

Comment: @Jani - are you confusing dynamic with ExandoObject?  AFAIK dynamic doesn't implement anything,  it's effectively just object with a flag that says defer binding until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you have a field rather than a property. The below shows an example of how to iterate through all the members of a type. You can filter down using FindMembers instead of GetMemebrs

```
public class Reflector
{
    public void ShowMembers(object o)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        foreach (MemberInfo member in type.GetMembers())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is a {1}", member.Name, member.MemberType);
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code against a button and you get something like:

```
...skip...
ManipulationDelta is a Event
ManipulationInertiaStarting is a Event
ManipulationBoundaryFeedback is a Event
ManipulationCompleted is a Event
IsDefaultProperty is a Field
IsCancelProperty is a Field
IsDefaultedProperty is a Field
...
```

So just to be clear:

```
Public string a;
```

is a Field, while

```
public string a { get; set; }
```

would be a property.

I didn't actually answer the question. That's clever of me.

```
public class Reflector
{
    public void ShowMembers(object o)
    {
        Type type = o.GetType();
        foreach (MemberInfo member in type.GetMembers())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is a {1}", member.Name, member.MemberType);
        }
    }

    public void Set(object o, string fieldName, int val)
    {
        MemberInfo[] info = o.GetType().GetMember(fieldName);
        FieldInfo field = info[0] as FieldInfo;
        field.SetValue(o, val);
    }

    public int x;
}
```

If I call `reflector.Set(reflector, "x", 10);` so I'm calling Set on itself, the above method will set the value to 10. If you want to read the value it is GetValue.

Comment: sorry but i don't get it if i don't know the name of fieldName how to Use GetValue?

Comment: That's fair enough, all the bits are there. ShowMembers has a loop which iterates through all members of a class. If you run that code against your object, you'll see a list of all the members and what sort it is, i.e. Field, Event, etc. Set here actually sets a field to a value. So by combining both, putting a call to Set inside the loop of ShowMembers where MemberType== MemberType.Field you'll win :)