# Way to take advantage of dynamic stuff introduced in .NET 4 to get properties and fileds by name

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

It's a question that comes to my mind when I look for a solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518346/getting-objects-properties-values-without-knowing-their-name).

Since `dynamic` class implements `IDictionary<string,object>`, Is there any way to get properties of an object by assigning to a `dynamic` variable (I don't want the intended class to implement `IExpando` interface).

It's just a matter of curiosity, I know that there are many ways to do that.

Comment: It's my understanding that `dynamic` objects don't know about members until they are requested at runtime, and this is done through a series of TryGet* methods.  There's an example of creating a custom dynamic object here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx  I'd be surprised if it somehow simplified reflection.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean when you say dynamic implements `IDictionary<string, object>`?

To answer the question directly I would say the answer is no.  However it's easy enough to iterate through the properties of an object using reflection,  there is no need for dynamic.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = myObject.GetType().GetProperties()
```

Turning myObject into dynamic doesn't change anything here - you're just asking the compiler to defer the binding of the methods until runtime.

Answer (score 2):

There is some confusion in the question regarding the statement:

> "Since dynamic class implements IDictionary"

It is `ExpandoObject` that implements the `IDictionary` interface, not the `dynamic` type.

For example:

```
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

    obj.Apples = 5;
    obj.Oranges = 1;
    obj.Bananas = 2;

    var properties = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;

    properties.
        ToList().
        ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Property={0},Value={1}",x.Key,x.Value));
```

Output:

> Property=Apples, Value=5
>
> Property=Oranges, Value=1
>
> Property=Bananas, Value=2

This is not much use to you in terms of the question i.e. using the new dynamic features of .NET 4 to get properties and fields by name.

You cannot apply the `ExpandoObject` mechanism to an existing type and use it as a generic mechanism for 'reflecting' on its properties.

You must continue to use reflection and 'type.GetProperties' for now.